# Why is "Application.ScreenUpdating = False" not working?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm put some code together which changes the row and column fields of some pivot tables based on a selection from a drop down.

1. I can't seem to get the `application.screenupdating = False` to work no matter where I put it in my code and no matter how many times.
2. Is there a way to clean this code up as I've basically duplicated a chunk of it for each selection from the drop down.

The following code is embedded in the sheet I'm working with:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim pvt As pivotTable
Dim pf As String
Dim pf_Name As String
Dim pvtf As PivotField
Set pvt = Sheets("Exit Interviews").PivotTables("Question")
Set pvt2 = Sheets("Exit Interviews").PivotTables("Question2")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then

'This section is duplicated for each drop down selection //
If Range("$B$2").Value = "Question1" Then

    On Error Resume Next

    For Each pvtf In pvt2.ColumnFields
    pvtf.Orientation = xlHidden
    Next pvtf

    pf = "Question1"
    pf_Name = "Question1 "

    pvt2.AddDataField pvt.PivotFields("Question1"), pf_Name, xlSum
    pvt2.PivotFields("Question1 ").Orientation = xlColumnField

    For Each pvtf In pvt.RowFields
    pvtf.Orientation = xlHidden
    Next pvtf

    pf = "Question1"
    pf_Name = "Question1 "

    pvt.AddDataField pvt.PivotFields("Question1"), pf_Name, xlSum
    pvt.PivotFields("Question1 ").Orientation = xlRowField
'//

    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Just an FYI: sometimes the `Application.ScreenUpdating` reverts to True if the code either hits a breakpoint or has an issue which diverts to the code editor.

Comment: Do you get an error if you remove the `On Error Resume Next`? I'm also not sure what you mean by `Application.ScreenUpdating` not working. Does the screen update as you step through it with a debugger?

Comment: What's the difference in the duplications? The range being checked and the hardcoded string? Or are there other differences as well?

Comment: *This section is duplicated for each drop down selection* - consider putting that code in its own parameterized procedure then, passing a parameter for each value that needs to be different. You'll remove the need for such duplication.

Comment: I've removed 'On Error Resume Next' and it appears to have fixed the issue. I put this in there originally as some other code was stopping the drop down selection running the code if that drop down item was already selected. 
I removed the dodgy code but never removed the error resume code.
Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: Just remember to turn it back on before you exit the sub